# Android Kotlin - Navigate between fragments using textView in recyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, onclick, android-navigation

I would like to navigate between fragments using a textView inside a recyclerview.

Currently I am successfully navigating between fragments using the item, but I would like to go further and navigate using the individual textViews within an item.

The recyclerview is inflated from a local room database.

Below is my adapter

```
package com.benb.inventory

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.benb.inventory.data.Item
import com.benb.inventory.data.getFormattedPrice
import com.benb.inventory.databinding.ItemListItemBinding

class ItemListAdapter(private val onItemClicked: (Item) -> Unit) :
    ListAdapter<Item, ItemListAdapter.ItemViewHolder>(DiffCallback) {

    class ItemViewHolder(internal var binding: ItemListItemBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(item: Item) {
            binding.apply {
                itemName.text = item.itemName
                itemPrice.text = item.getFormattedPrice()
                itemShop.text = item.shop.toString()
                itemShop.setOnClickListener{
                    val shopName = itemShop.text.toString()
                    Toast.makeText(root.context, "Clicked: ${item.shop}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show()

                }
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private val DiffCallback = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Item>() {
            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Item, newItem: Item): Boolean {
                return oldItem == newItem
            }

            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Item, newItem: Item): Boolean {
                return oldItem.itemName == newItem.itemName
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): ItemListAdapter.ItemViewHolder {

        return ItemViewHolder(ItemListItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemListAdapter.ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val current = getItem(position)
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            onItemClicked(current)
        }
        holder.binding.itemShop.setOnClickListener {
            onItemClicked(current)
            val shopName = current.shop
            fun showShopList(shopName: String) {
                val shopName = holder.binding.itemShop.text.toString()
                val action = ItemListFragmentDirections.actionItemListFragmentToShopItemFragment(shopName)

            }
        }
        holder.bind(current)
    }

}
```

This is the fragment that contains the list

```
package com.benb.inventory

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.activityViewModels
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.benb.inventory.databinding.ItemListFragmentBinding
import kotlinx.coroutines.InternalCoroutinesApi

@InternalCoroutinesApi
class ItemListFragment : Fragment() {

    @InternalCoroutinesApi
    private val viewModel: InventoryViewModel by activityViewModels {
        InventoryViewModelFactory(
            (activity?.application as InventoryApplication).database.itemDao()
        )
    }

    private var _binding: ItemListFragmentBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = ItemListFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val adapter = ItemListAdapter {
            val action = ItemListFragmentDirections.actionItemListFragmentToItemDetailFragment(it.id)
            this.findNavController().navigate(action)
        }
        binding.recyclerView.adapter = adapter

        viewModel.allItems.observe(this.viewLifecycleOwner) {items ->
            items.let {
                adapter.submitList(it)
            }
        }

        binding.itemShop.setOnClickListener{
            val shop = binding.itemShop.text.toString()
            val action = ItemListFragmentDirections.actionItemListFragmentToShopItemFragment(shop)
            viewModel.retrieveShopItems(shop)
            this.findNavController().navigate(action)

        }

        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context)
        binding.floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener {
            val action = ItemListFragmentDirections.actionItemListFragmentToAddItemFragment(
                getString(R.string.add_fragment_title)
            )
            this.findNavController().navigate(action)
        }
    }
}
```

For clarity this is what the inflated recyclerview looks like, it can contain many items, I have only added one.
At the moment if I click anywhere on the item it takes you to a screen with more detail about the fragment.

[A screenshot of the recycler view][1]

I would like to be able to navigate to a specific fragment depending on the textView clicked.
For example one fragment that only contains other products from the same shop.

As you may notice, I have been able to add an onClickListener in the ViewHolder class, it creates a Toast.
I have not had success in using the same onClickListener to navigate.

Thank you very much.
P.S. Any other advice is welcome, particularly if anyone knows what the @internalcoroutinesAPI thing is about please tell me!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6Td3.png

Comment: You have not added the fragment code.

Comment: @DarShan thank you for pointing that out.

Should be visible now